# GParted physical block size error

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to use `gparted` from a LiveUSB of Mint 18.  When I open `gparted`, it throws an error box

> The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.

I've tried looking up information on this, but I can't find anything elementary enough.  In small words, please, what causes this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=2048 count=1
```

This will change the block size of sdX. Then you can create you live-usb. Remember: of=/dev/sdX must point to your usb path.

PS. I readed from a ubuntu forum but I didn't save the link.
Edit. I forgot add count=1

Comment: That is essentially a disk geometry error which in your case and many others is safe to ignore but the above command should rectify it on that drive.

Comment: why 2048？ why count=1? Isn't this dependent on the hardware? Also, which one is right, linux or the driver descriptor? Thanks