# libParted error: the driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes

Tags: ubuntu, gparted

I am trying to format my SSD and every time I open GParted, it says "the driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes". I followed the method listed at [GParted physical block size error](https://superuser.com/questions/1112147/gparted-physical-block-size-error) and similar methods using DD but they did not work and I still get the warning. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And [this](https://superuser.com/a/1153220) method helped me out....

Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type in the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdZZZ bs=2048 count=32 && sync
```

Replace ZZZ with the correct letter, given to your removable device. For example /sdb